# How do I remove Webmynd from Chrome when it doesn't even show up on my list of extensions?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

It only shows up when I browse google.com...

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some searching, I learned that it masquerades under the "Search tabs" extension.